# cannot connect android to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-assistant

I am trying to connect my android app to firebase. In android studio when i click the button "connect to firebase" ,the loading menu came.. and no action still. I waited for 15 minutes,it is still loading . As I am new to this ,I don't know how to connect it. Can you what's the problem in this?. I've checked my internet also,it is working properly when i browse. [image]

Comment: I would recommend you going to the friebase website and start a project from there. It provides a step by step tutorial on how you can implement firebase into your project

Comment: After that you should read the docs regarding the implementation you should implement into your project. This provides a much safer way as you will have more control

Comment: Try to delete .gradle directory from android project, restart android studio and build again.

Comment: @creamy oreo , I've already tried by going to firebase website and connecting. the same thing happened there. it stucked  in  the message "checking your app has communicated withour server" , I' waited for a long  time, but still loading.

Comment: A suggestion I could give you is to recreate your project and directly connect through the website supposedly this is a fresh new project

Comment: This problem is not only to this project. It occurs in all the projects i have. I cannot connect any project to firebase. I've recreated it many times

Comment: I have had this issue before, the fix for me was to restart your computer and then android studio. Go to tools firebase and configure your firebase connection from there. Note I recommend having the firebase console open as well. If this does not work create the firebase project inside the console and then link up to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last update, when you click on the contact button the download appears, you must go to the official website of Firebase and click on Add Project and it will appear to you as shown in the picture

You choose the project name and add **SHA1**

[image]

Comment: I tried this way. It showing that the app has connected , But  I can't use any of the firebase resources. Refer to my question in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/a/61822441?noredirect=1". Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: ,Can you give your contact number or mail id? I would talk to you about few things on android. My mail id "sec19it097@sairamtap.edu.in".